# Make ESXi VM use client network

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, internet

Is it possible to make the ESXi VM to use the network that from where the remote console to the VM (in question) is initiated?

For eg. I have a VM "VM1" on an ESXi.

I am initiating the remote connection via RDP/vSphere Thick Client/vSphere Web Client from my computer called "MyComp".

Can I make "VM1" use "MyComp"'s network?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a network redirection feature built into the vSphere client.

So unless you somehow can convey the network's traffic to the vSphere host by other means (VLANs, bridges or some kind of bridging VPN or a suitable NAT configuration), the answer is "No".

Answer (score 1):

Certainly your management network can be in the same VLAN and thus IP-space as your VMs and they can share the same uplink port too. You do this by having a single vSwitch0 but with both a management port group and a VM-facing port group, both can either be on the same or different VLANs or even could go untagged altogether.

Not saying this is the best solution, it's really not if you're only using 1Gbps NICs and especially not if you're also using 1 1Gbps NIC for your storage too but that does work - there's no routing going on, just layer-2 but it might be what you're after.

Comment: No, you didn't understand my question completely. I was asking if I can share the same network of "MyComp" with "VM1" akin to using the CD/DVD drive of "MyComp" as a CD/DVD Drive of "VM1".

Comment: Well they can both be on the same port group - perhaps you could clarify your question further?